# About generator of symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutations

I read [this link](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) . In Theorem $2.7 $, it is mentioned that for $n\geq 3$ except for $n = 5, 6, 8$, symmetric group $S_n$ is generated by an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$. However,  we also know that for $n\geq 2$, $S_n$ is generated by the transposition $(1 2)$ and the $n$-cycle $(12\ldots n)$. If we use later result then $S_4$ is generated by transposition $(1 2)$ and  $4$-cycle $(1234)$ which contradicts result of Theorem $2. 7$ since order of four cycle is four.

Could anybody explain me where I am going wrong? I would be very much grateful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can not see the contradiction, why do you think that $|(1,2,3,4)|=4$ cause a contradiction.

Comment: You get $(1234)$ as the product $(12)(234)$, so $(12)$ and $(234)$ generate all of $S_4$ confirming that Theorem in the case $n=4$. You have to be extra careful in selecting the elements of order two and three that do generate the group. Also - what amWhy says.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for clearing my doubt.

Comment: @mesel Thanks for the response.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theorem doesn't claim that $S_n$ is **only** generated by a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle. It claims that it *can* be generated by these.

The fact that $S_4$ can *also* be generated by a 2-cycle and a 4-cycle is not a contradiction. Note that $S_4$ can very well be generated by a $2$-cycle and a $3$-cycle: Take, e.g., $\langle (1, 2), (2, 3, 4)\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My doubt is cleared.

Comment: You're welcome, srijan!